# Dell dual HDD, dual boot, hide the two systems from each other

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have Latitude E6540 which I got from the company I work for. I installed an SSD in the optical bay to boot my own Windows image which I can use for whatever I want (unlike the company one).
My question is: Is there any method to completely hide the two systems from each other whithout physically removing the drives? I'm thinking about a BIOS mod or something, which automatically enables the selected HDD and disables the other one. I was overhearing that there exists a BIOS update that enables this but I cant seem to find it.
I need this because the company OS has a drive encryption, and when I first booted the company OS whith my SSD left in the machine, it automatically encrypted my drive (luckily no important data was lost in the process). After this event, I manually disabled the SSD in the device manager and it seemed to work. But I do not trust this method, so I'm constantly removing/reinstalling the SSD.

If my system 'sees' the company drive, that's not a problem, since it is encrypted. Also, I thought about encrypting my SSD myself but that seems too much of a hassle.
Thanks!

Comment: Similar issue here, but it shows you how to hide the other drive while booted into one of the OS's this registry modification would have to be done while booted into each os....http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/127417-system-restore-points-stop-xp-dual-boot-delete.html

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a solution that kinda works: In the BIOS, under system configuration -> drives if I disable Sata-1, my SSD in the optical bay is indeed disabled and cannot be seen by the company OS. Similarly, Sata-0 corresponds the internal HDD.
But this is nearly as much effort as physically removing the drive.